# Git fails to tag

Tags: git, github

After running any git command dealing with tagging except for list it prints 70 to the terminal and hangs until I terminate it. It also does it when I specify a commit made. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Command Ran:

```
git tag -a iteration2-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an annotated (-a) tag requires a message. Your git editor is likely misconfigured, and git is trying (and failing) to open the editor to type the tag message. Try passing the message on the command line, e.g., `$ git tag -a iteration2-1 -m 'this is iteration2'`

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on the version of Git, and OS (Linux, Windows, Mac) used: see for instance "[git operations occasionally hang in Jenkins on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10732940/6309)".
From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26351627/6309), if you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, try and **[upgrade git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309)** (with a 2.2+) to see if the issue persists.

Note that [`git tag -a`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) is suppose to *create* a tag, not to list one.
That means it should be `git tag -a tagname acommit`.